# Time Chart Drawing in Java

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am somewhat new to the graph visualization in Java and I am trying using JFreeChart Library,

I currently have 2 array's :

1st Array is an array of Integer values.

2nd Array is an array of Dates.

I would like to draw a graph where Date is on X-Axis and Integer Value should be on Y-Axis. Could anybody help how I can create such graph.

I already checked XYLine Chart, but the problem is dataset only takes integer as input but I have to put date.

Any other suggestion how I could create such chart.

Answer (score 2):

Your X axis will need to be a `TimeSeriesCollection`.

See the following [Time Series Demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartTimeSeriesChartDemo1therendererismodifiedtoshowfilledshapes.htm).
You can find other examples by searching for [JfreeChart Time Series](http://google.com/search?q=jfreechart%20time%20series)

UPDATE:
To address the fact that some classes and methods have been `@deprecated` but the example still uses them - you will need to modify the example as follows:
1) Delete any references to: `TimeSeriesCollection::setDomainIsPointsInTime(...)`
it is not requred because:

```
 /* @deprecated This flag is no longer used, as of 1.0.1.  The
  *             <code>includeInterval</code> flag in methods such as
  *             {@link #getDomainBounds(boolean)} makes this unnecessary.
  */
```

2) Remove the second parameter from `TimeSeries(..., ...)`. It is not required because:

```
 /* @deprecated As of 1.0.13, it is not necessary to specify the
  *     <code>timePeriodClass</code> as this will be inferred when the
  *     first data item is added to the dataset.
  */
```

Comment: Yeah, even I also check the same but I don't understand, in my Java API it is saying TimeSeriesCollection constructor is Deprecated or it can not be no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the date to a long with

```
public long getTime()
```

and then to an Integer by using mathematical means of your choice.

For a Gantt representation, take a look at Jaret Timebars (GPL): http://jaret.de/timebars/